# External drive not in fdisk, but lsusb

Tags: 18.04, usb, mount, external-hdd

mounting my external harddrive stopped working. It's not showing at any mountpoint and of course not in Nautilus. Any advise?

** UPDATE **

It mounts to `/media/$USR/Elements` with USB 2.0. Outputs below for USB 3.0

** /UPDATE**

Outputs of different commands below - please notify, what else may be helpful.

`sudo fdisk -l` shows my 2 internal drives **only**:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2B2758A3-8728-4D4B-8B82-56CFFE7DB3CC

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    1085439    1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1085440    1288191     202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1288192    1320959      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1320960  450559999  449239040 214,2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  450560000  489621503   39061504  18,6G Linux swap
/dev/sda6  489621504  880246783  390625280 186,3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  880246784 1953523711 1073276928 511,8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00095dd3

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 488396799 488394752 232,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`lsblk | grep -v loop` as well:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   529M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 214,2G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  18,6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0 186,3G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0 511,8G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 232,9G  0 part /home/$USR/dtn
```

Now, `lsusb` shows the Western Digital on `Bus 003`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:02d2 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1058:1042 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements SE Portable (WDBPCK)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: default mount location is in `/mnt`, so can you provide the result of `ls /mnt`?

Comment: Hey, thanks! `ls /mnt` showed nothing, as well as the `/media` dirs. 
However, I just plugged it into my only USB 2.0 and it mounted. So it's most likely a USB 3.0 issue!?

Comment: it's probably an hardware issue

Comment: can you please show us the output of *dmesg* when you connect your drive?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with module uas.

Create file `/etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage.conf`

with following content.

```
options usb_storage quirks=1058:1042:u
```

easy way is to reboot, after that.